# Camera is showing black after try to open from custom endpoint

Tags: android, kotlin, endpoint

I was developing an app which act as API REST, and have an UI layer too, to show some data.

What a I try to do is an endpoint in my API which when it have been called, open the camera of the device who make the call, and then return the content of the image as a ByteArray.

My problem doesn't comes from the API development, which works fine, is with the process which open the camera, which start the activity, but show a black screen which freeze the app too.

The workflow of the API call is

Here is my Activity:

CameraActivity.kt

```
class CameraActivity : ListenerCompatActivity() {
    companion object{
        const val TAKE_PICTURE = 1
    }
    private val useCase = Application.useCaseManager.deviceManagement
    private lateinit var ui: ActivityCameraBinding
    var timeStamp: String? = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    var imageFilePath: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString() + "/Android/data/com.my.app/Image-" + timeStamp + ".png"

    private var resultSent = false
    override fun getActivityID(): ActivityID = ActivityID.Camera

    override fun isKeepScreenOn() = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ui = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(ui.root)
        ui.footerLogo.load(R.drawable.logo_name_big)
        ui.cmdQRCancel.setOnClickListener{sendCancelResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)}
        startCameraIntent()
    }

    private fun startCameraIntent() {
        /*************************** Camera Intent Start  */
        val imageFile = File(imageFilePath)
        val imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile) // convert path to Uri


        // Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera
        // application capture an image and return it.
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri) // set the image file name
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE)
        /*************************** Camera Intent End  */
    }

    private fun sendCancelResult(resultCode: Int) {
        sendResult(
            resultCode,
            ApiCameraResponse().also { it.setFailed(Messages.CANCEL_BY_USER) }
        )
    }

    private fun sendResult(resultCode: Int, result: ApiCameraResponse) {
        logger.info("Sending result = $result")
        resultSent = true
        //Keep the base64 content
        //TODO: Save camera result
        useCase.setApiCameraResponse(result)
        val msg = MessageFactory.cameraResult(resultCode, result)
        TaskPool.UI.launch {
            if (!sendToService(msg)) {
                logger.error("Failed to send Camera data to service")
            }
            runOnUiThread { finish() }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        Log.d("*********", "Request Code:$requestCode")
        //For the ImageCapture Activity
        //For the ImageCapture Activity
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                /*********** Load Captured Image And Data Start  */

                // Decode it for real
                val bmpFactoryOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false

                //imageFilePath image path which you pass with intent
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, bmpFactoryOptions)

                val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)
                val byteArray = baos.toByteArray()
                Log.d("**********", "byteArray: $byteArray")
                sendResult(
                    resultCode,
                    ApiCameraResponse(ApiCameraResponse.Info(success = true, result = ApiCameraResponse.Result(
                        failed = false,
                        success = true,
                        message = applicationContext.getString(R.string.camera_save_succesfully),
                        cameraContent = Base64.encode(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT),
                        cameraType = "PNG",
                    ))))
                    .also {
                        resultSent = true
                    }
                /*********** Load Captured Image And Data End  */
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, " Picture was not taken ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        }else{
            sendCancelResult(resultCode)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logic of my domain class, which is working fine:

DeviceManagmentUseCase.kt

```
var cameraResponse: ApiCameraResponse = ApiCameraResponse()
    suspend fun openCamera(request:ApiCameraRequest):ApiCameraResponse{
        logger.info("pinpad/openCamera $request")
        var resp = ApiCameraResponse()
        taskController.runShortTask {
            it.uiActivities.startActivity(
                ActivityID.Camera,
                MessageFactory.forFinish()
            )
            resp = cameraResponse
            Log.d("*********", "Camera response en open camera:resp: $resp cameraResponse; $cameraResponse")
        }
        return resp
    }

    fun setApiCameraResponse(resp: ApiCameraResponse){
        cameraResponse = resp
        Log.d("**********", "Camera response en setCameraResponse: cameraResponse: $cameraResponse resp: $resp")
    }
```

And here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="***************">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- MISC PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="*******.permissions.RESTART_SERVICE" />

<application
        android:name=".app.AndroidApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:restoreAnyVersion="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true">

<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "*******://**********" -->
                <data
                    android:host="************"
                    android:scheme="********" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

 <!-- Utility activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.BarcodeCameraScannerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.InternalBarcodeScanActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.CameraActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

I don't know if I'm missing some permission here, due to I know this problem usually comes which some issue like this, but I'd say I have the main ones.

Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

I add a provider in my manifest inside application tag:

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="***************.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

and add the file.path.ml file in res/xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="intent_images"
        path="Pictures"
        />
</paths>
```

I also change the way I get the imageUri like this:

```
private fun startCameraIntent() {
        /*************************** Camera Intent Start  */
        val imageFile = File(imageFilePath)
        val imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext, "******************", imageFile) //Convert file to Uri

        // Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera
        // application capture an image and return it.
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri) // set the image file name
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE)
        /*************************** Camera Intent End  */
    }
```

Despite this changes, when the endpoint is called, open the camera, but screen get freeze.

Any clues?

Comment: `val imageFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile)` -- this has not worked for several years. Please use `FileProvider` and supply a `Uri` obtained via `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In order to implement your solution I need to define a provider in manifest file. Do you know how to manage this?